# SSIS package automated deployment from repository to file system

Tags: tfs, ssis

We have some SSIS packages which we are trying to automate using TFS so that the packages will be picked from repository instead of local machine of developer and then those packages can be deployed to file system. I tried to build the SSIS package solution file using TFS but there is no output, might be because MSBuild cannot understand SSIS packages. Please let me know if you have any idea of how to deploy the SSIS packages from TFS repository to a file system. Well I can easily change the configuration and setup to one environment, but my need is that it has to happen through TFS.

Comment: Have you tried simply using devenv?

Answer (score -1):

I tried to configure my SSIS Project but I was unable to do so because I was using SQL Server 2008R2 and TFS was 2012. So, I was facing compatibility issue.

However! These links might help you automating your deployment.

1. [Integration Services (SSIS) and Visual Studio Team Foundation Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn463982.aspx)
2. [Automating SSIS Package deployement using TFS](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d7296785-61e7-4f18-858a-91821b998706/automating-ssis-package-deployement-using-tfs?forum=tfsadmin)
3. [Automating SSIS 2012 ‘Project’ Deployment](http://sqlscape.wordpress.com/2012/06/05/automating-ssis-2012-project-deployment-5/)
4. [TFS vs SSIS project versioning](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/jamesserra/2013/03/26/tfs-vs-ssis-project-versioning/)

Many pardons for this Linkuish answer!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My main concern is that, the SSIS packages are developed in SQL BIDS 2008 and we are using TFS 2010. Is there any solution to this so that I can automate the SSIS package deployment to a file system using TFS 2010.